# Should a Service Worker be registered in the manifest or through a script?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Most examples of registering a Service worker do so through JavaScript. For example (From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker#Examples)):

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', {
    scope: './'
  }).then(function (registration) {
    var serviceWorker;
    if (registration.installing) {
      serviceWorker = registration.installing;
      document.querySelector('#kind').textContent = 'installing';
    } else if (registration.waiting) {
      serviceWorker = registration.waiting;
      document.querySelector('#kind').textContent = 'waiting';
    } else if (registration.active) {
      serviceWorker = registration.active;
      document.querySelector('#kind').textContent = 'active';
    }
    if (serviceWorker) {
      // logState(serviceWorker.state);
      serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', function (e) {
        // logState(e.target.state);
      });
    }
  }).catch (function (error) {
    // Something went wrong during registration. The service-worker.js file
    // might be unavailable or contain a syntax error.
  });
} else {
  // The current browser doesn't support service workers.
}
```

But I noticed in the [Web App Manifest standard](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#serviceworker-member) that there is a `serviceworker` member:

```js
"serviceworker": {
  "src": "sw.js",
  "scope": "/",
  "update_via_cache": "none"
}
```

This is the only place I've seen this referred to.

This raises two questions for me:

### 1 Which approach SHOULD I use? What are the trade-offs?

The declarative benefit of the manifest approach is obvious, but if I use that approach, how do I reference the registration object in order to track events similar to the script approach? (**installing** | **waiting** | **active** | **failed**).

Assuming it IS possible to reference the registration object appropriately, can it miss events? Such as finish installing before I could register an event listener to it.

### 2 What are the caching implications

Since the manifest would be saved in the offline cache, and this manifest would reference the service-worker script, what are the cache implications? Does the 24 hour rule still apply assuming I do NOT store the script in the offline cache? The `update_via_cache` member is not a simple thing to read in the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was added to the spec [back in October of 2016](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/commit/9e5567af0fee8681061c2b7f5359c1d0fd84a901), and there is some background discussion in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/161).

My interpretation is that the use case is providing service worker bootstrapping metadata that is relevant when installing a web app via a non-browser mechanism, e.g. via an app store. I don't see any mention of that field in the [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/microsoft-store#automatic-pwa-importing-with-bing) about Microsoft Store ingestion, though.

So... as of right now, I am not clear that any browsers honor the `serviceworker` field in the web app manifest, and if your concern is having a functional service worker registration for "browser" use cases, do it using JavaScript.

Your best bet for follow ups would be to ask on the web app manifest's [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues).

Comment: Is there any update on this? As I tested, it seems the browser just ignores service worker declaration in the manifest!

Comment: MDN now lists this as deprecated without reasoning: <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/serviceworker>